# Creating a Function - Errors

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle-apex

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crimes_tied_officer
DECLARE
lv_witness_check VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN 
Hi Guys

I am trying to create a function for a database I am developing for a project. However, it is throwing up errors gallore!

The present error is
    Error at line 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

```
   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with

    << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge

1. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crimes_tied_officer
2. DECLARE
3. lv_witness_check VARCHAR(40);
```

I have included my function code below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crimes_tied_officer
DECLARE
lv_witness_check VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN 
IF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = '800' THEN
lv_witness_check := 'External Observation Witness';
ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 801 THEN
lv_witness_check := 'Expert Witness';
ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 802 THEN
lv_witness_check := 'Partner or Spouse';
ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 803 THEN
lv_witness_check := 'Police Officer';
ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 804 THEN
lv_witness_check := 'The Accused';
ELSE lv_witness_check := 'No Witness Type Selected';
END IF;
RETURN lv_witness_check;
END;
```

My tables are at the following links.
http://gyazo.com/0d01e276984bf464be36db075fc62e56

http://gyazo.com/de5c17891455e01fcf81b32f86fab80c

Comment: create function **as** and not **declare**. Also you need to specify what type it **returns**. An [example here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5009.htm#i2062371) provided should help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you also need to specify a return type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crimes_tied_officer(FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS
    lv_witness_check VARCHAR2(40);
  BEGIN
    IF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID    = '800' THEN
      lv_witness_check       := 'External Observation Witness';
    ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 801 THEN
      lv_witness_check       := 'Expert Witness';
    ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 802 THEN
      lv_witness_check       := 'Partner or Spouse';
    ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 803 THEN
      lv_witness_check       := 'Police Officer';
    ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 804 THEN
      lv_witness_check       := 'The Accused';
    ELSE
      lv_witness_check := 'No Witness Type Selected';
    END IF;
    RETURN lv_witness_check;
  END;
```

Comment: Error at line 5: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

3.     lv_witness_check VARCHAR2(40);
4.   BEGIN
5.     IF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID    = '800' THEN
6.       lv_witness_check       := 'External Observation Witness';
7.     ELSIF FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID = 801 THEN is returned on that code.

Comment: is "FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID" a parameter?

Comment: Added the parameter, so make sure when you call it, you pass it the 'FK1_WITNESS_TYPE_ID', can you accept my answer if that is working for you?